# Dictionary values missing

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am doing the very last exercise on http://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter5/.  For some reason I am not able to get the `displayInventory(inv)` function to return the correct values outside of the `addToInventory()` function.

Here is the code:

```
def displayInventory(inventory):
    print("Inventory:")
    item_total = 0
    for k, v in inventory.items():
        print(str(v) + ' ' + k)
        item_total += v
    print("Total number of items: " + str(item_total))

def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for k in addedItems:
        if k in inventory:
            inv[k] = inv[k] + 1
            print('You have ' + str(inv[k]) + ' ' + k + 's')
    else:
        print(k + ' is not in inventory')
        inventory.setdefault(k, 1)
print()
displayInventory(inv) #does work

inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
displayInventory(inv)
print()
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)
print()
displayInventory(inv) #Doesn't work
```

I get the error:  `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'`
It looks like the `inv` dictionary is empty.  Why it is emptied and why the values are different outside of the function?

Comment: `addToInventory` doesn't explicitly return anything (and shouldn't, by convention, as it mutates its argument) - so why are you assigning the `None` default return to `inv`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `addToInventory()` function returns `None`, because you don't have a specific `return` statement.

Since the function alters the dictionary *in place*, you should just not use the return value; remove the `inv =` part:

```
# ignore the return value; do not replace `inv` with it
addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)
```

Comment: Thank you.  It looks like that does solve the issue.  For the sake of this conversation, how would you use the `return` statement in this instance?

Comment: You could add `return inventory` to the end of the function; that would return the same dictionary again. But note that in the Python standard library functions and methods that alter an object in-place return `None` by convention (e.g. `list.sort()` or `dict.update()`).